# How do I pass a reference to a pandas series into a dictionary?

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, reference

So I need to assemble a dictionary of pandas series' and I was wondering if it would be faster to just pass a reference to the series instead of copying over all the data into the dictionary. I have the code:

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
dict = {
    'Start' : df['Start']
        }
print(dict.get('Start'))
```

I tried to change the data to see if it was copying over the data so I did

```
dict = {
    'Start' : df['Start']
        }
df['Start'] = df['End']
print(dict.get('Start'))
```

but this didn't change the output of the code at all, showing that the dictionary contains a copy of the series. I think this would be slower than just passing a reference so is it possible for me to just assign a reference to the value inside the dict?

Comment: No copies are being made here when you add to the dictionary. Python will never implicitly copy data like that some third party library may do something like that for a third-party container, but none of the built-in containers work like that.

Comment: But really, taking a step back, *why on earth are you creating a dataframe of series*. A dataframe, for all intents and purposes, can already function as a dictionary of series...

Comment: Code changes output on my system. Does it happen that `df` is a slice of a bigger dataframe?

Comment: In any case, doing `df['Start'] = df['End']` then `print(dict.get('Start'))` **does not demonstrate that a copy of the series has been made**. It almost certainly hasn't (although, sometimes pandas will copy underlying data, in this case it probably doesn't)

Comment: @QuangHoang whether or not it changes will depend on the underlying dataframe. Dependingon the types, `df['start'] = df['end']` will either mutate the underyling buffer being shared with the series in the dict or not. For example, if dtype "Start" is `int64` and dtype `"End"` is `float64`, not effect will be seen, the block manager will change the underyling representation of the dataframe

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga yes, same as I experienced. It does change,  if `Start` and `End` have same data type, it doesn't if not.

Answer (score 0):

```
 df['Start'] = df['End']
```

Is not a reliable way to test this. Basically, `pandas` makes no guarantees (or not a lot) about underlying buffer that represents the data in the dataframe. All of this relies on implementation details, the block manager will try to keep things stored efficiently in like-typed blocks, which is possible if the dtypes are homogenous, but in the case of hetergenous dtypes

```
df['Start'] = df['End']
```

Could potentially re-arrange the way the dataframe is represented.

A more reliable way to test the copying behavior is to modify a single element without changing the type of the column. So assuming `"Start"` is all integers:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"start":[1,2,3], "end":[4,5,6]})
>>> df
   start  end
0      1    4
1      2    5
2      3    6
>>> d = {'start':df['start']}
>>> df.loc[0, 'start'] = 99
>>> d
{'start': 0    99
1     2
2     3
Name: start, dtype: int64}
```

But I'm not sure about any guarantees that pandas makes about `df[column]`, but in my experience, it always returns a view. However, it is a view of the underlying data in the block manger *at that time*. Mutating your dataframe can easily change that underlying buffer.